# Not able to use jiffy and flutter_localizations because different versions of intl

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use the `Jiffy` package and the `flutter` localization package. Problem is now, that both are using the intl package, but with different versions. When I try "Packages get" I get the following error:

> Because every version of flutter_localizations from sdk depends on intl 0.15.8 and every version of jiffy depends on intl ^0.16.0, flutter_localizations from sdk is incompatible with jiffy.

Is there a way to solve it? To use both version of intl for example?

Thanks

Comment: This might help to override the [Dependency](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages#conflict-resolution)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You just need to add this to your `pubspec.yaml` file:

`dependency_overrides:
  intl: ^0.16.0`

Comment: You'right, I had intl: ^0.16.1  it didn't work ,   I have to change to  ^0.16.0

Answer (score 1):

go to your pubspec.yamal and 
under of  `global_configuration`:

set intl version like this :

```
     dependency_overrides:
  intl: ^0.15.8
```

and change it to :

```
dependency_overrides:
 intl: ^0.16.0
```