# image_size_getter install error (Because every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on collection [...]) [flutter]

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop

I'm trying to install [image-size-getter](https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/image_size_getter#-installing-tab-) on my flutter desktop project.

When i add this to my package's pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  [...]
  image_size_getter: ^0.1.0
```

i get this error:

> Because every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on collection
>   1.14.11 and every version of image_size_getter depends on collection  ^1.14.12, flutter_test from sdk is incompatible with
>   image_size_getter. So, because example_flutter depends on both
>   image_size_getter ^0.1.0 and flutter_test any from sdk, version
>   solving failed.

I tried to solve that issue by ovveriding dependencies as i found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51375674/error-after-running-flutter-upgrade) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58802307/not-able-to-use-jiffy-and-flutter-localizations-because-different-versions-of-in) (i must be on the futter master channel):

```
dependency_overrides:
  flutter_test: ^1.14.12
```

But now it seems that flutter_test package is not available:

> Because example_flutter depends on flutter_test any which doesn't
>   exist (could not find package flutter_test at
>   https://pub.dartlang.org), version solving failed. pub get failed
>   (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 1 in 1 second... Because
>   example_flutter depends on flutter_test any which doesn't exist (could
>   not find package flutter_test at https://pub.dartlang.org), version
>   solving failed. pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting
>   retry 2 in 2 seconds... Because example_flutter depends on
>   flutter_test any which doesn't exist (could not find package
>   flutter_test at https://pub.dartlang.org), version solving failed. pub
>   get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 3 in 4 seconds...
>   [..]

I upgraded to last `master` channel version, this is my `flutter doctor` output:

```
    PS C:\flutter\200229_flutter-desktop-embedding-master\example> flutter doctor
    Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
    [√] Flutter (Channel master, v1.15.4-pre.239, on Microsoft Windows [Versione 10.0.18362.657], locale it-IT)

    [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    [√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.4.3)
    [√] Android Studio (version 3.0)
    [√] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2017.2)
    [√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.42.1)
    [√] Connected device (1 available)

No issues found!
```

How i can i solve my issue?

Comment: Have you checked [this article](https://pratikbutani.medium.com/flutter-2-upgrade-flutter-version-solving-failed-error-33ac1087cb6b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flutter_test` is not a regular package that you can override the version for - it is a part of the Flutter SDK.

What you can do however is override the version of `collection` such that both `flutter_test` and `image_size_getter` use the same version and no longer conflict.

Try this:

```
dependency_overrides:
  collection: ^1.14.12
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your latest `collection` plugin

```
dependencies:
 collection: ^1.14.13
```